# Can anyone here read handwritten calligraphy and can tell me what this says please? It's on a porcelain plaque

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Can anyone here read handwritten calligraphy and can tell me what this says please? It's on a porcelain plaque.

[image: writing]

Comment: At some stage, we expect you to start learning how to read this yourself.

Comment: I'm really trying to learn, but handwritten stuff is very difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

願與彭澤令同醉菊花天
王倚(琦)寫於珠山

愿与彭泽令同醉菊花天
王倚(琦)写于珠山

彭澤令 implies [陶淵明](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E9%99%B6%E6%B8%8A%E6%98%8E) ([Tao Yuan-ming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Yuanming)) because he has been the 彭澤令 (Pen-ze county magistrate) and loved 菊花 very much。

菊花天 implies the autumn because 菊花 (chrysanthemum flowers) blossom in the fall.

珠山 implies the 江西景德鎮 because it is a famous hill there.

王倚 may be a mimic name of 王琦 who was a famous artist in the porcelain area several decades ago.

The stamp shows 王印, and the two characters have the inverse colors.

> 願與彭澤令同醉菊花天
>   Hope to drink (wine) with Tao Yuan-ming in autumn.

Comment: Here's a photo of the plaque. https://i.imgur.com/YLkvK0K.jpg